# Conditional urn balls with replacement

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $w$ white and $b$ black balls. What is the conditional probability of drawing white on $i$th and $j$th draw given a total of $s$ white in $n$ extractions with replacement? ($i<j$, $s<n$)

$$\Pr(E|F)=\frac{\Pr(E\cap{F})}{\Pr(F)}$$

where:

- F: I get $s$ white on $n$ extractions
- E: white on $i$th and $j$th draw

Now, E and F should be indipendent, so $\Pr(E|F)=\Pr(E)=\frac{w}{w+b}\frac{w}{w+b}$

Am i correct?

---

I edit with the correct solution provided by lulu:

"Given that there are $s$ white draws all in all, the probability that the $i$th draw was white is $\frac{s}{n}$. Then the probability that the $j$th draw was also white is $\frac{s-1}{n-1}$"

The final answer is $\frac{s}{n}\frac{s-1}{n-1}$

Comment: "given that a total of $s$ white in $n$ extractions with replacement" -> can't understand, maybe the verb is missing?

Comment: If $s<2$, $P(E|F)=0$, but $P(E|F')>0$, so $E$ and $F$ don’t seem independent.

Comment: @MarcoDisce it was a typo, I hope now is more clear.

Comment: @SteveKass good point, so if $\Pr(F)=\binom{n}{s}{p_w}^{s}{p_b}^{n-s}$ then how I can find $\Pr(E\cap{F})$?

Comment: Given that there are $s$ white draws all in all, the probability that the $i^{th}$ draw was white is $\frac sn$.  Then the probability that the $j^{th}$ draw was also white is $\frac {s-1}{n-1}$.

Comment: That's right, brilliant solution!

Comment: Make it an answer.